# How do I resolve this error when installing packages in a Conda venv?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install pygame in my python 3.6.10 Conda venv. When I ran: `conda install -c cogsci pygame`
it gave me an unsatisfiable error saying: `- pip -> python[version='>=3.7,<3.8.0a0']` (I am on windows 10 btw). Does this mean that my version of pip requires python 3.7? How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the full output?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like you need to upgrade your python to version 3.7.
Upgrade your python to 3.7.x but not to 3.8 as it says >=3.7 , <3.8